# readLine() does not return any value

Tags: sockets, readline

When I try to execute this code, server correctly gets the data that I send, however client does not print "response". Program goes into infinite loop at readLine() line and even "Something" String is not printed. What might be the problem?

```
class SecuritySystemClient {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception{

        byte [] a = {0, 0, 13, 98, 105, 108, 107, 101, 110, 116, 58, 99, 115, 52, 50, 49};

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 80);

        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        outToServer.write(a, 0, a.length);
        outToServer.flush();

        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String response = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Something");
        System.out.println(response);

        clientSocket.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the server implemented? Maybe the server is waiting for more input before sending the response, maybe it does not send a line-separator after the response

Comment: The client is sending a binary request, consisting of a 3-byte header followed by a 13-character 8-bit string. The header *likely* consists of a 1-byte request type and 2-byte payload length, but that is a guess. However, the header does contain 13, which is the actual string length. The server likely sends back a similarly binary response, which would not satisfy `readLine()` (or `Reader`, for that matter). Try reading the response as bytes instead of text and see what you get.

Comment: For instance, read 3 bytes, convert the last 2 bytes to an integer, and then read however many bytes that integer says. If that doesn't work, then you need to show the actual response bytes being received, maybe someone will be able to make sense of them for you.  Or, do you have any documentation that describes this protocol you are trying to implement?